# Smooth scrolling between in-page links

Tags: javascript, jquery

For long web pages, I have a "back to top" function that, when clicked, smooth scrolls the page back to the top.

The button looks like this, on the bottom right corner of the page:

[image]

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

  // display and hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt'): $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
  });

  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
  });
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/my-web-page/" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

It works fine. As a user scrolls down, the arrow appears and, when clicked, smooth scrolls them back to the top. No problem.

**The problem is in-page links**. When a user clicks on any links like this:

```
<a href="/my-web-page/#section-3">text text text</a>
```

... the page just jumps to the section, in the default manner.

Here's what I have so far to make the smooth scrolling work for in-page links.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'), 
        skip = false;
    for (i = 0; i < exceptions.length; i++) {
      if (href.indexOf(exceptions[i]) > -1) {
        skip = true;
      }
    }
    if (!skip) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

It doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, if we can combine the in-page function with the main script, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the `for` loop which contained the `exceptions` reference and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply applying `scroll-behavior: smooth` to the document eliminates the need for any JavaScript, since it makes all anchor links scroll smoothly.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior):

> The scrolling box scrolls in a smooth fashion using a user-agent-defined timing function over a user-agent-defined period of time. User agents should follow platform conventions, if any.

---

To make the "back to top" anchor scroll to the top, simply set the `href` to `#`.

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#last">jump to last section</a>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section" id="last"></div>
<a href="#" class="back-to-top make-visible-btt">Back to Top</a>
```

---

To make the original jQuery code work, simply remove the problematic `exceptions` reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

  // display and hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt'): $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
  });

  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'),
      skip = false;
    if (!skip) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#last">jump to last section</a>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section" id="last"></div>
<a href="/my-web-page/" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```